# how do i program abyss web server X2 URL Rewriting to produce a Mediawiki short url

Tags: mediawiki, url-rewriting

All of the refernces i find expplaining how to complete this are incorrect for this web server.
i have the tools to do this URL rewriting what i need is a real how to complete this.

i have abyss web server X2 installed with PHP

Mediawiki URL is / and /wiki

If anyone can be straight forward and answer
i am on a dedicated production server and i can't make errors.

Thanks.

Comment: Nevermind i self taught myself waiting for this answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind i self taught myself waiting for this answer. Thank you though.

Using the process of elimination and trail and error i figured out how to do it.

I logged into my Abyss Web Server X2 Console.
I Clicked configure on the host i needed to configure.
 
I clicked on URL Rewriting.
I Enabled Rule checking the box. 
I set the type to global.
 
For Virtual Path Regular Expression i typed ^/wiki/(.*)$
I did not check the chech box to enable Case Sensitive.
I chose these two Variable  Operator options below for the Conditions. 
REQUEST_FILENAME    Is not a file
REQUEST_FILENAME    Is not a directory
I checked the check box to enable  Apply to subrequests.
I chose If this rule matches Perform an internal redirection. 
I chose to Redirect to  /wiki/index.php?title=$1 
i enabled the two check boxes
Append Query String 
Escape Redirection 
And finally i chose Next Action Stop matching

Step 2
I opened my mediawiki 1.29 alpha localsettings.php and typed.
$wgScriptPath = "/wiki";        # may already exist
$wgArticlePath = "/wiki/$1";    # tells MediaWiki how IIS will be rewriting URLs
$wgUsePathInfo = true;     # mine was false you may have to set yours to true

and that's all now i have the Mediawiki Short URLS on my Abyss Web Server X2

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/Abyss